# Defining an interface to pass byte[] and byte* between C# and C++?

Tags: interface, c++-cli, argument-passing

Given the following test interface (C#):

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    UInt32 Simple(UInt32 someArg);

    byte* Read(UInt32 count);
    void Write(byte* buf, UInt32 count);

    byte[] ReadArray(UInt32 count);
    void WriteArray(byte[] buf);
}
```

Can I implement this interface in c++/cli?  I've tried a million different ways; currently I have this:

```cpp
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32;
typedef unsigned char byte;

public ref class CTest : public ITest
{
  virtual uint32 Simple(uint32 someArg);

  virtual byte * Read(uint32 count);
  virtual void Write(byte * buf, uint32 count);

  virtual System::Array<byte>^ ReadArray(uint32 count);
  virtual void WriteArray(System::Array<byte>^ buf);
}
```

The VC2010 compiler complains bitterly about all of the methods except CTest::Simple, claiming I haven't implemented the interface.

Can someone show me the c++/cli magic to implement an interface that passes either byte* or byte[] (preferably both)?  I'm at my wit's end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiles:

```cpp
public ref class CTest : public ITest
{
public:
    virtual unsigned Simple(unsigned someArg) { return 0u; }

    virtual unsigned char* Read(unsigned count) { return nullptr; }
    virtual void Write(unsigned char* buf, unsigned count) { }

    virtual array<unsigned char>^ ReadArray(unsigned count) { return nullptr; }
    virtual void WriteArray(array<unsigned char>^ buf) { }
};
```

Your main problem is the fact that your `CTest` member functions are private and thus ineligible to implement the interface. The other problems are mostly related to using `System::Array<>` rather than `array<>` (which is short for `cli::array<>`).

Comment: So I had everything properly declared as public; I just didn't actually try to compile my example.  It turns out that the root of my problem was that I had been working for 14 hours when I tried to figured this out, and had a typo in the method name of my implementing class.  D'oh!  Anyway, thanks for the quick response...